# Loading Excel sheet in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Timeout error while loading excel sheet name in Azure Data Factory. Size of the file is 51 MB. Do we have any size restriction for Excel? No Articles on this on MSDN

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2cRN.jpg

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @LeonYue It's timeout error.

Comment: Which active did you use to set the source dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I've loaded 10+ GB CSV files from Azure Blob Storage without ADF flinching in the slightest.

Not sure where your file is hosted, but try staging it in Azure Blob Storage first since the proximity to ADF will optimize retrieval.  Beyond that, try referencing your source file as a CSV instead, if possible.  To get a specific sheet out, you may have to write a simple little Azure Function to programmatically pull that sheet out of the XLSX and stage it as a CSV as a workaround.

Comment: Same here, but I now have the same problem on a 56 MB Excel file that I successfully imported two weeks ago. "The file is big and will lead to interactive operation timeout", so I used a sample file to preview the data and import the schema, but then the import failed with the same message after more than one hour. Tried again half day later, I get an OutOfMemory exception. ADF service health doesn't seem to have issues, not sure what happens.

Comment: I can confirm that importing the file as CSV works, even though the CSV file ended up being three times bigger that the Excel file in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try sample data with a much smaller size. ADF has limitations to show sheet name if the file is "too big". You will be able to do it with smaller size.